# Click once deployment to support multiple versions

Tags: c#

Can click once support multiple versions of the application like (DEV,UAT,Prod)?

Click once files are copied in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0`

If we launch UAT version of the application then try to launch Prod version then UAT binaries are overridden by prod version.

Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

If we follow [this link](http://www.helplessautomation.com/2011/02/clickonce-deployment-deploying-multiple-versions-of-the-same-application/) and change the assembly name then if we are using Assembly name in app.config for particular types then it will cause problem.

Comment: I found [PackageWeb (DemoVideo)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LvUJFI8CzM) [PackageWeb Nuget Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PackageWeb/) pretty useful for this (building once, deploying to multiple [different] targets) It might need some individual tweaking to make it work for your special case, but set up correctly it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use unique Certificate file for each different environment. You can use actual cert for your PROD and then create dummy/test certificates for other environments. Use those dummy certs for building your non-prod deployments. Use Mageui or the mage command line to build your deployment and application manifest.

You can follow this instructions on [MSDN to create dummy certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx).

Also you may have to set "Create Application without a manifest" on the application properties: Right click on the project->properties, on  Application tab set->Icon and Manifest->Create Application Without a manifest.

You can review the steps outlined in [MSDN for manually deploying ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It shows you how to create manifests with certificates from Mage command line or Mageui.